# Error starting APP from xib file

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was using Storyboards to start the APP but in the end i have had to remove them. So, i have changed in Xcode the option Main Interface to my controller. Now, when i start the APP i get the next error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0x711d750> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.
```

In my AppDelegate i have the next function

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This kind of issues occur because your Outlets might not be connected properly or deleted by mistake, so make sure you are connecting your `IBOutlet` Properly, e.g. you might have an outlet link in an XIB/storyboard that points to an `IBOutlet` in your code that no longer exists.

Secondly make sure you are adding your root Controller on `UIWindow` in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, something like this

```
self.window.rootViewController = yourRootViewContoller;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```